# Join cell value into one cell when matches exist

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this four columns

```
 Handle           Title          Images                   Joined Images                  
 Dalmas HG       Dalmas HG      http://4b1e4d.jpg    http://4b1e4d.jpg,http://ee78e4.jpg, http://7390f6.jpg
 Dalmas HG                      http://ee78e4.jpg
 Dalmas HG                      http://7390f6.jpg
 Klyftig         Klyftig        http://7390f6.jpg
 Klyftig                        http://8ffa40.jpg
 Klyftig                        http://f1627e.jpg
 Klyftig                        http://f21eda.jpg
 Klyftig                        http://6001d2.jpg
```

Then I would like to join the images if they have the same handle.
But I cannot find out the riddle on how to.

This is how I'm trying to solve it

```
   DALMAS   =if(A2=B2,JOIN(",", C2:C4),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C,3,FALSE)))
KLYFTIG =if(A5=B5,JOIN(",", C5:C9),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C,3,FALSE)))
```

Returns : http://4b1e4d.jpg,http://ee78e4.jpg, http://7390f6.jpg

But that means that i manually needs to change the index when I getting to the next handle.

Any ideas on how to solve this more dynamically?
I have this spreadsheet that have the formulas.

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mMZvMhRuhj4WNgOxXtAT0S3Ys9WrlrXHOAOjACwAjW0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a [copy of your sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YuI4Fs_EyDhK5GhZWA_WNqBNfq0NSwX_Mj_mL4b52wc/edit?usp=sharing).

This formula seems to work, and should work for up to about 5,000 images? maybe more.  depends on how many sets there are.  it uses what I (and some others) call a Query() "smush".  It's a sort of a trick using the query header parameter to join a whole bunch of data together by column.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(IF(TRANSPOSE(D2:D)=VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A),FILTER({ROW(A2:A),A2:A},A2:A<>""),2),B2:B&CHAR(10),),,9^9)),CHAR(10),",")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would like to have the output but if you want a joined list of all jpeg's per name, you could try

```
=arrayformula(regexreplace({unique(A2:A), trim(transpose(query(if((transpose(unique(A2:A))=A2:A)*len(A2:A),B2:B&",",),,50000)))},",$", ))
```

Note: I removed the leading spaces before some of the names.

[image: Screenshot]